# Expression (!a && b) || (!a && c) || (b && c) with minimum gates

Tags: boolean-logic

I want to create a logical circuit

`(!a && b) || (!a && c) || (b && c)`

using as few logical gates (~ a nand b) nand `NOT`, `AND`, `OR`, `NAND`, `NOR`, `XOR`, `NXOR` as possible. The gate types can be mixxed. I have found some online calculators that can convert the above expression to NANDs  only like

`(!a nand b) nand (!a nand c) nand (b nand c)`

But I wonder if there is a way to do it by using less than four gates.

Comment: An equivalent using several less operations could be `(!a && (b || c)) || (b && c)`

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on either the CS or EE stack exchanges. This is not a coding problem.

Answer (score 1):

Four gates and one inverter seem to be minimal:

[image]

This result was created by [Logic Friday 1](https://logic-friday.software.informer.com/1.1/).

```
Entered:
f = (!a & b) | (!a & c) | (b & c);

Minimized:
f = a' b  + a' c + b c;
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like it cannot be minimized more than this: `a'b + c(a' + b)` or can even be written as follows `a'(b + c) + bc`

[image: kamp]

which is actually identical to `a'b  + a'c + bc` (has same truth table).